# undefined method when returning an array in object.find(:all, :conditions)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm using:

`rails 2.3.9
 ruby 1.9.3
 windows 7 ultimate
 rubygems 1.8.24`

This works:

```
@inventories = Inventory.find :first, :conditions => {:siteId => params[:siteId]}
```

This doesn't

```
@inventories = Inventory.find :all, :conditions => {:siteId => params[:siteId]}
```

Error message:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `siteId' for #Array:0x49738f8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rails 2.x your syntax is slightly wrong
If you want to find all records with certain conditions then try this example which uses multiple conditions

```
@inventories = Inventory.find(:all, :conditions => ["siteId=? and priority=?", params[:siteId], 3])
```

Comment: i'd like the siteId to be the only condition. when i try: 
@inventories = Inventory.find(:all, :conditions => ["siteId=?", params[:siteId]]) the error persists.

Comment: @AldrinDelaCruz I'm sure it did work. Perhaps the error is not on the find but on a line after the find. Post the full stack trace of your error from your development.log file

Comment: yes james, i'm so sorry. it was in rendering the xml after executing this query.

Answer (score 0):

when you write

```
@inventories = Inventory.find :first, :conditions => {:siteId => params[:siteId]}
```

Above line give you a single (first) object of the `Inventory` depending on the default order which matched the given condition so you can use `@inventories.siteId`. However when no row matches the given condition it will return nil and in such case if you try to use  `@inventories.siteId` it will throws an error `undefined method`siteId' for nil`

But when you write

```
@inventories = Inventory.find :all, :conditions => {:siteId => params[:siteId]}
```

Above line gives you an array of the objects of `Inventory` no matters if your query returns the 1 or more than 1 objects i.e. row and blank array i.e `[]` if now rows satisfies the condition. So, when you try to use `@inventories.siteId`, you are actually applying siteId on Array and not on the object of `Inventory` and it will throws an error `undefined method`siteId' for #Array`. However following will work properly

```
@inventories.each{|p| puts "#{p.siteId}"}
```

Comment: this might be a noob question, but I'm trying to query all inventories with siteId = 17.